# Can't remove ghost branch github/BLOB

Tags: git, github, sendgrid

My email provider identified an exposed API key and created a branch from my github repo:

[image]

I removed my `config.js` file from my repo and from what github says I only have one branch.

[image]

The file still exists because they sent me a link to that specific file and that's where that branch with that file show.

I've tried switching branches, creating a new branch named just like it but nothing. How can I remove that file or the entire branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link your provider sent you is probably to a specific commit.  Even if that commit has been rebased out of your history and you've force-pushed, GitHub doesn't normally prune old commits, so they'll still be accessible.

You *must* assume that any secrets you've pushed to a public repo are compromised.  You should revoke that API key and generate a new one, in which case whether GitHub persists the commit doesn't matter.  This is the standard security best practice for this case.

If you really need it removed from the history, [GitHub has a document](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#purging-a-file-from-your-repositorys-history) that describes the procedure for doing that.

Comment: Had to delete the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, even if you added a new commit to remove it from `master`, the *commit* remains in `master`'s history.

Note that `cbe85dc` is not a branch, but a commit. It is part of `master`'s history, and if you have a public GitHub repository, then anyone can see it even if you remove the API key in a later commit.

I would proceed by using interactive-rebase to edit this commit to remove the api key.
At the same time you can drop the commit where you remove the api key (is it won't make sense anymore to remove the API key when it's already removed).

**Warning**: This involves rewriting history, and requires a force-push to correct on GitHub. This is discouraged if there are several contributers on the repository, or you have it cloned to multiple computers, as everyone would need to "hard-reset" or delete and re-clone their local repository after you force-push to `master`.

### If you determine that is OK, here is how I would proceed:

```
git rebase -i cbe85dc~1
```

This will open up interactive-rebase in your editor, which looks something like this

```
pick cbe85dc Some message
pick abcdef  Another message
pick defabc  Yet another message

# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
...
```

Now, change `pick` to `edit` for `cbe85dc`.
You should also see the commit where you later removed the API key, for this commit you can change `pick` to `drop` to remove the commit.

Save and exit your editor, and you should be in a "rebase" state for editing `cbe85dc`.
Now remove the API key, and amend the commit (update the file, `git add` the file, then `git commit --amend`).

Then `git rebase --continue` to replay every later commit on top of your change.
Now, if everything has worked out, you can force-push your changes to github with `git push origin master -f`

At this point commit `cbe85dc` is no longer a part of `master`'s history, and will be removed by garbage collection after some time. The edited commit gets a new hash. You should still consider the API key compromised and get a new one.

---

Alternatively you could use the `filter-branch` command, but this also rewrites the history, and requires force-push etc. Personally, I would use interactive-rebase, since that is what I'm used to.

For more information, see [here from the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but when I use `git rebase -i cbe85dc~1` the commit `cbe85dc` does not exist.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good, then perhaps you managed to remove it from `master`'s history already 

Comment: Does `git fetch origin && git show cbe85dc` give the same message?

Comment: To answer your first question, it's still in github and I need to remove it from there

About the second one, they give completly diferent messages, the first one says something about `unpackaging` and the second one show kind of a whole commit

Comment: Aah, is `cbe85dc` the first commit in this repository?

Comment: If yes, you can use `git rebase -i --root`. Make sure you are on branch master when you run this command.

Comment: The `config.js` file exists from my first commit but I've added things to it in later commits.

Comment: Had to delete my repo. Voted up because it's still useful. Thanks!